# Update from 16.04. to 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Yesterday I Updated my Laptop from 16.04. to 18.04.

The process took approx 3 hours, and seemed to be normal. After the 1st reboot, the Installation was confirmed as 18.04. LTS. Unfortunately, the Desktop was still showing the old/previous Unity, instead of Gnome (which I was hoping for).

Last year, I did the same thing with my Office PC, and everything was fine (with Gnome).

Is this normal? Does anybody here know if there is a fix for Gnome?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you enter your password, do you see a gear-type icon where you can select which DEsktop you want to use for that session.  Unity is still supported in 18.04 (community support) and you may find you can use GNOME or Unity, selecting at login.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing gnome:

```
sudo apt install tasksel
```

then execute and you should be good to go.

```
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: No. Just select the proper desktop at login time, as per @guiverc